# Is there a guidline for Scripting for ScadaLTS?

Tags: javascript, bacnet, scadalts

I have been using the relase version SCADA-LTS v2.6.18 for since a year. In most cases for Modbus TCP and BACnet TCP, to collect data for the trend logs.
Now I want do send an action from the "grafical view" to a device on the network. Therefor I want to write the value 3 on the DP_921176 alias VU_OG1_Stufe_Local.

Here some pictures of my porgess:
`[Datasource setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbvIj.png) [Grafical views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R7It.png) [scripting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWYjt.png) [Modern watch list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjigh.png)`

I have already tested difernet writings of the javascript without an impact on the value of DP_921176.

Can you help me to understand the syntax of writing a smiple script in Scada LTS, please?

Thank you very much.
Marmor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a documentation, but a frind helped me. The writing of the script was wrong. This is how it is working for me:

```
val_2.writeDataPoint('DP_921176', 3);
```

I still haven't understood what the "context points" are needed for.

Also I have missed to set the checkbox "Settable" by "Data source". But now it works as expected.